# Is it illegal for my school to locally install monitoring software on my Chromebook (bought from outside of school)?

Tags: monitoring

My school has installed monitoring software on my Chromebook that we didn't get from the school, unlike most other students. Software, such as [Impero](https://www.imperosoftware.com/), that can see my screen and remove access to developer mode and the Linux development environment, to which I would greatly prefer access.

Comment: Hi and welcome to the site! This quesiton is more related to law than it is to security, so I will suggest that it is migrated to the law stack exchange instead. (Still, them messing with your computer without your permission sounds very sketchy...)

Comment: Are you certain that it is the school?

Comment: This can be migrated, but you will first need to indicate what jurisdiction this is in (i.e. where are you?)

Comment: "They installed it" -- did you give them permission? How did they install it?

Answer (score -1):

Regardless of the legality, it's of course very inconvenient. Sadly, many schools will insist on installing spyware to monitor online tests and it is legal in many jurisdictions.

A way to both give you privacy and developer access, while also allowing the school to monitor school-related activities, would to install the spyware only on the user account which is linked to your school account, and not on your administrator account.

Comment: School monitoring software usually requires kernel or admin access (so it can't be turned off) so this suggestion won't work.

Comment: It's not about the user but the system files it changes... and it probably needs admin rights for that...